# how to navigate without contextless

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I get this error when I open the App.

when I am trying to initialize the router  from authStore get this error

```
"You are trying to use contextless navigation without
      a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
      If you are testing your app, you can use:
      [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
      a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
      for a [GetMaterialApp].
      "
```

main.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: Get.key,
      smartManagement: SmartManagement.full,
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Ponte Delivery',
      initialRoute: Routers.home,
      getPages: Pages.getPages,
      theme: Themes.light,
    );
  }
```

```
class InitialBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<LocalStorage>(() => LocalStorageImpl());
    Get.put<HttpClient>(HttpClientImpl(Dio()), permanent: true);
    Get.put<AuthStore>(AuthStore(Get.find<LocalStorage>()), permanent: true);
   
  }
}
```

AuthStore

```
 @override
  void onInit() {
    ever(isLogged, fireRoute);
    super.onInit();
    token = _storage.read(TOKEN);
    user = _storage.read(USER, construct: (map) => UserModel.fromMap(map));
    if (token == null && user == null) {
      isLogged.value = false;
    }
  }

  fireRoute(logged) {
    print(logged);
    if (!logged) {
      Get.offNamed(Routers.initialRoute);
    }
  }
```

I am using already GetMaterialApp.
I tried to use debugger and I got error in this Line

```
      Get.offNamed(Routers.initialRoute);
```